# Mismatch on antlr 4.4 runtime jar with antlr maven plugin 4.4

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to build my antlr project using antlr 4.4.  I am running with Maven but there seems to be a mismatch on the distributions of these tools.  The only distribution of antlr-maven-plugin 4.4 that I can find is from Tunnelvision Labs.  When I use their version of the runtime jar and maven plugin, my build fails.  It can't find org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Pair.

I tried to use the antr-runtime-4.4.jar from antlr.org, but it won't work with antlr-maven-plugin from Tunnelvision Labs. It returns an error 'cannot find symbol:  RuleVersion'.

The only version I could get to work was building my own from the source distribution on antlr.org.

Is there a distribution available from antlr.org that includes antr-maven-plugin-4.4?

Comment: The org.tunnelvisionlabs artifact does not contain any references to a Pair class. It sounds like you have another version of the runtime listed in your system class path, or are otherwise referencing an org.antlr artifact.